# React setState side effects with Form Data

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, react-redux

Sorry for the general title but I don't know what else to call it at this point.  I have a form that uses widgets.  Im using the react-jsonschema-form package.  Id use the github for the project but I don't think this is bug so I want to check here first.  I think it's just how to use this React thing question.  Possibly Redux as well.

So...

I have these widgets for some of the form elements in my component.

```
     dropdownWidget = (props, type, id) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <input id={id} type="text" className="form-control" list={type} placeholder="Select one..." onChange={(event) => { props.onChange(event.target.value); this.hideResultTables(event.target.id) }} />
            <datalist id={type}>
                {this.props.actionsObj.filterJsonData(type, this.props.convertDropDownDataObj).map((value, index) => { return <option key={index} value={value}>{value}</option> })}
            </datalist>
        </div>
    )
}

multiFileWidget = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <OverlayTrigger trigger={['hover', 'focus']} placement="right" overlay={fileWidgetPopup}>
                <input type="file" id="multiFileName" required={props.required} onChange={(event) => { props.onChange(event.target.value); this.getFileNames(); this.hideResultTables(event.target.id) }} multiple />
            </OverlayTrigger>
            <textarea id="multiFileNameList" className="form-control" rows="4" style={{ marginTop: "2%" }} readOnly />
        </div>
    )
}


dropdownTooltipWidget = (props, type, id, tooltip) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <OverlayTrigger trigger={['hover', 'focus']} placement="right" overlay={tooltip} hidden>
                <input id={id} type="text" className="form-control" list={type} placeholder="Select one..." onChange={(event) => { props.onChange(event.target.value); this.hideResultTables(event.target.id) }} />
            </OverlayTrigger>
            <datalist id={type}>
                {this.props.actionsObj.filterJsonData(type, this.props.convertDropDownDataObj).map((value, index) => { return <option key={index} value={value}>{value}</option> })}
            </datalist>
        </div>
    )
}
```

They are stuffed in a object like so:

```
     multiUISchema = {
    file: {
        'ui:widget': this.multiFileWidget,
        classNames: "uiSchema",
    },
    convertTo: {
        'ui:widget': (props) => this.dropdownWidget(props, "ConvertToTypes", "multiConvertTo"),
        classNames: "uiSchema"
    },
    notification: {
        'ui:widget': (props) => this.dropdownTooltipWidget(props, "NotificationType", "notification", websNotificationPopup),
        classNames: "uiSchema"
    }
}
```

Where things go bad!!  This function is injected in the widgets onChange handler.

```
     hideResultTables(targetId) {
    debugger;
    //disable Retrieve button
    if (targetId === 'multiFileName' || targetId === 'multiConvertTo') {
        console.log("BEFORE::", this.state.formData)
        selectedFiles = [];
        document.getElementById("convertResultTable").setAttribute("hidden", true);
        document.getElementById("retrieveResultTable").setAttribute("hidden", true);
        this.setState({ disabled: true });

    }
    //leave Retrieve Button enabled
    else if (targetId !== 'appIDs') {
        console.log("BEFORE::", this.state.formData)
        selectedFiles = [];
        document.getElementById("convertResultTable").setAttribute("hidden", true);
        document.getElementById("retrieveResultTable").setAttribute("hidden", true);
    }
}
```

Basically if I hit the first if statement which has the setState for disabled to True, my onChange doesn't seem to retain the selected dropdown data to the Form Data object.  It's like setState for Disabled true, which is for a button unrelated to the field does something to in the reconciliation tree possibly and/or my form data never retains the selected field in the formdata object at all??  idk.  The field just stays undefined in all console logs if it's a field that hits that first if statement with the setState in it.  But that setState has nothing to do with the fields being selected.  It's disabling a button further down the page is all.  Im sure im missing some React lifecycle, reconciliation async something or other.  Im thinking of just reduxing this all but this simple bool value seems like it should stay as local state to the component.  Any thoughts on things I should be checking before i redux this simple bool for my form?

To Further clarify my question, why does setState in the injected function in onChange seem to disrupt the onChange value update for the field on the form in my Widget when I select a field.  That's really what this is all about.  We cannot figure out why this is happening.

footnote**  The dropdown data in the form is redux store data.  So im selecting store data in my onchange in the widgets.  Not sure if that's relevant.

Comment: I can't tell what your question is. Could you clarify by asking one specific question?

Comment: Thanks @stone  I tried to further clarify the question above and I added this bit at the end.  To Further clarify my question, why does setState in the injected function in onChange seem to disrupt the onChange value update for the field on the form in my Widget when I select a field.  That's really what this is all about.  We cannot figure out why this is happening.